# How to return the vaules of several variables based on the minimum value in a specific group

Tags: r

I'm working with the database in the titanic library.

The columns names (variables) are as follows:
Age
Name (string)
String (integer 0/1)

I would like to find the youngest and the oldest passenger who survived and to **print their Name with their age.** The bold one it the part I can't to get around.

This is the code I came up with to find the min/max Age of survivors
df = passengers2

```
min(passengers2[passengers2$Survived==1,]$Age, na.rm=TRUE)
max(passengers2[passengers2$Survived==1,]$Age, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

one way, using {dplyr} and the pipe:

```
library(titanic)
library(dplyr)

titanic_train |>
  filter(Survived == 1) |>
  slice(which.min(Age), which.max(Age)) |>
  select(Name, Age)
```

```
                                  Name   Age
1      Thomas, Master. Assad Alexander  0.42
2 Barkworth, Mr. Algernon Henry Wilson 80.00
```

evaluate per sex:

```
titanic_train |>
  filter(Survived == 1) |>
  group_by(Sex) |>
  slice(which.min(Age), which.max(Age)) |>
  select(Name, Age)
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Sex [2]
  Sex    Name                                   Age
  <chr>  <chr>                                <dbl>
1 female Baclini, Miss. Helene Barbara         0.75
2 female Andrews, Miss. Kornelia Theodosia    63   
3 male   Thomas, Master. Assad Alexander       0.42
4 male   Barkworth, Mr. Algernon Henry Wilson 80
```

etc.